# Another way to say "to another level"

Tags: phrases

I am looking for another way to say take something to the next level.

Comment: What kind of something?  A user in a video game?  Or something more abstract?

Comment: Hey, an escalator! let's go up.

Comment: OP might be referring to the phrase "taking it to another level." Which is commonly used to describe the difficulty of an action or the act of going above and beyond in an activity. I don't think OP is literally referring to the progression of a game (advancing levels).

Comment: You could just go with **Improve** or [it's synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/improve).

Answer (score 3):

Per *dictionary.com,* to *[kick it up a notch](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/kick-it-up-a-notch)* is to...

> To make things more intense, exciting, or interesting.

- Lets *take this to another level*  →  Lets **kick it up a notch**.

Comment: Aw I was just about to add this to my edit! Great replacement for the phrase.

Answer (score 1):

> **Take it to another level**: Further improve or develop something that is already successful:
> five years after founding my software company, I’m ready to take it to the next level

The phrase I lean towards most often is "*a higher echelon...*.

More phrases similar to this include:

> - "*A higher tier*..."
> - "*A higher grade*..."

**Source:**
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/take-something-to-the-next-level

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to go "[up to eleven](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/up-to-eleven)."

[image]